# Periodic task not working when using crontab at given hour and minute

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, celerybeat

I'm trying to run a periodic task defined in a simple **python** script:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=43))
def every_day_morning():
    print("Good Morning!")
```

This is the command line I'm using:

```
python -m celery -A tasks beat
```

When I use `crontab(minute='*')` it works perfectly but, when I try it like:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=43))
```

it doesn't work (the task doesn't run).

I'm using `python 2.7`, and `celery 3.1.16` in Windows 8.1.

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean that the task does not run or is something else wrong?

Comment: the task doesn't run, even when I use `--loglevel=debug` I don't see any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your timezone! utc0 is celery default timezone！

U need to change it to your system timezone, like this:

```
pp = Celery(...)
app.conf.update(...
        CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'   # set timezone in here
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your timezone by running command in terminal

> timedatectl | grep "Timezone"

Update your celery app configuration

```
app = Celery()
app.conf.update(timezone='Asia/Kolkata')  # set your time zone here
```

Hope this helps